# How long do shrine effects last?

Tags: diablo-iii

Do the effects from shrines last a fixed or random amount of time?  Does the duration depend on the shrine?  Does it depend on the difficulty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shrine effect amount of time is fixed, and each shrine has the same time associated with it. Actually, when you activate a shrine, you will receive a buff, which you can look at directly above your skill bar. There will be one or several squares (one for each buff). Move your mouse over it to view it's effects and the remaining length.

Comment: Oh, cool, I didn't even think of trying mouseover...!  That said, does it vary with those other conditions or is it purely a flat value?

Comment: Oh.. totally forgot about the question with the difficulty. Unfortunately I cannot answer that question at this time, although I strongly assume that it will be the same. Right now, it's... 3 minutes for each one, correct? I can't imagine it going down any further. I do know that all shrines last the same time, though.

Answer (score 2):

Shrine effects in normal last for 2 mins.

From the few shrines I have seen most of the boosts seem to be 25% (to experience or attack speed etc.) - but this is just a pattern from seeing 3 shrines in Act 1.

Answer (score 1):

[Shrines](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/gameplay/objects#shrines) last 2 minutes. They can also be increased in time by the Gloves of Worship. The gloves of worship extend the time that [Shrines](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/gameplay/objects#shrines) last to 10 minutes.

[Pylons](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/gameplay/objects#pylons) last 30 seconds. They can not be increased in time. [Pylons](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/gameplay/objects#pylons) were added in Reaper of Souls expansion. And they can be found in [Nephalem Rifts](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/gameplay/adventure-mode#nephalem-rifts).